# how to remove duplicate varible django view.py

Tags: python, django

I'm getting a duplicate code in query, how can i merge 2 variable into 1 line

```
def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
    date_time = datetime.now()
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=request.user.id)
    transaction = TransactionVariant.objects.filter(transaction__pk=pk).update(deleted_at=date_time)
    transaction = Transaction.objects.filter(id=pk).update(deleted_at=date_time)
    serializer = TransactionSerializer(transaction, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, many=True)
```

my model:

transaction.py

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.TextField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    total = models.BigIntegerField()
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "transaction"
```

transaction_variant.py

```
class TransactionVariant(models.Model):
    transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transaction, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    variant = models.ForeignKey(Variant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "transaction_variant"
```

Comment: which two field you want to merge ?

Comment: I mean: transaction = TransactionVariant.objects.filter(transaction__pk=pk).update(deleted_at=date_time)
    transaction = Transaction.objects.filter(id=pk).update(deleted_at=date_time)

Comment: Is `TransactionSerializer`  only serializing the objects ? nothing more ?

Comment: Why you need this `transaction = Transaction.objects.filter(id=pk).update(deleted_at=date_time)` as already do same thing in previous line?